# Magento: редирект на главную страницу, если корзина пустая

Tags: редирект, redirect, magento

Собственно, весь вопрос в заголовке. Редирект на главную, это понятно:

```
_redirect(Mage::getBaseUrl())
```

Только вот где это в коде вставляется, не могу найти. По умолчанию мадженто загружает шаблон `noItems.phtml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал функцию `chooseTemplate()` в модуле `app/code/mage/checkout/block/cart.php`.

Вместо

```
$this->setTemplate($this->getEmptyTemplate());
```

написал

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
```

и все гуд!